# Data Structure that stores object with names

Tags: c++, object, vector, data-structures, struct

I want to store object that are given a certain name.

I wanted to use `struct` and then store them in a `vector`, but it was suggested to me that I should rather use a different data structure, a little more simple, but I cant seem to find one.

My current ("complex") solution:

```
//in header file
struct objStorage{
   Classname obj;
   string name;
};
vector<objStorage> vec;

//in constructor
objStorage firstObj;
firstObj.obj = new Classname();
firstObj.name = "foo";
vec.push_back(firstObj);
```

Is there a more simple solution (Data structure)?

I should add that I don't need the structure once I stored (copied?) it in the vector, because this is all happening in another class (constructor) so I don't want any problems when calling the constructor multiple times.

Comment: How do you want to use this? Look things up by name? List them in order of name? Also you set `obj` to `new Classname` and `"foo"` - so this won't compile. And who deletes the `new Classname()`?

Comment: I need to look them up by name later, yes. I meant firstobject, i'll edit that. The destructor takes care of Classname deletion

Comment: Why don't you go for a hash map? This is not a rhetorical question, I want to know if there's some special requirement due to which you cannot use it.

Comment: @Happy I'm new to c++ so i haven't thought about that. I'll look it up right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to lookup items by some key, for example a string, the classic thing to use is a `map`:

```
std::map<std::string, Classname> items;
std::pair<std::map<std::string, Classname>::iterator, bool> inserted =
    items.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("foo"), Classname()));
items["bar"] = Classname();
```

In this set up, if you really think you want to use pointers, you should consider some form of smart pointer.

There are other options, for example, C++11 introduces other lookup structures - e.g. unordered maps.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, I come from java but completely forgot about maps